# .htaccess do a 302 redirect instead of 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I must do a non-www redirect to www. It must be a 301 redirect but for some reason I do not understand, it do a 302 redirect... Here my code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [L,R=301]
```

As you can see I wrote `[L,R=301]`. But when I test my code I see it does a 302 redirect. I have used fiddler and the following website to test:

[URL Redirect Checker](http://www.contentforest.com/seo-tools/redirect-checker)

The website I am testing is [renovahaus.it](http://www.renovahaus.it) and as you can see, the redirects work, but not the status code.

How can I solve the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if that is connected, but I would like to mention that it looks like you have a serious issue in that `RewriteRule`: if you really use that inside a `.htaccess` style file as your tagging suggests (as opposed to the real host configuration) then you have to add a slash (`/`) between host and path part in the target of the `RewriteRule`. Inside `.htaccess` style files the request path offered as subject to the regular expression is a _relative_ path, thus without leading slash.

Comment: Do you have any other redirects?

Comment: @starkeen, no I do not think, in the pages I just have some canonical links (1 per page).. for example in the home page: `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.renovahaus.it/" />`

Comment: @arkascha, do you mean in this way: `http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1`?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Otherwise you get an invalid URL, I'd say, with unpredictable outcome.

Comment: No, I obtain a double // you can check on the URL Redirect Checker :(